# i want to fetch that from mysql database using codeigniter framework php?

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I want to fetch that through model

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `visits`, `shortdes`, `photo` FROM `products`
         WHERE  `name` LIKE '$word'
         OR `shortdes` LIKE '$word' ANd  `valid` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

I used that, but it returned false

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
$this->db->like('name', $word);
$this->db->or_like('shortdes', $word);
$this->db->where('valid', 1);
$this->db->select('id, name, visits, shortdes, photo');
$query = $this->db->get('products');
```

What can i use?

Comment: Have you setup the database.php file in the config folder? This needs to point to your database with your credentials. If you remove the WHERE, SELECT, LIKE, etc methods, so just have `$query = $this->db->get('products');` Does this work?

Comment: yeah it gives me a result but that i doesn't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging codeigniter's query builder query's, I usually reccommend doing something like this to debug them and see exactly what query the statements are producing.

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
$this->db->like('name', $word);
$this->db->or_like('shortdes', $word);
$this->db->where('valid', 1);
$this->db->select('id, name, visits, shortdes, photo');
$query = $this->db->get('products');

echo "<pre>"
die(print_r($this->db->last_query(), TRUE));
```

When ran, it will output the actual raw SQL query being produced, and you can then debug it from there.

Comment: it gives me that `SELECT `id`, `name`, `visits`, `shortdes`, `photo`
FROM (`products`)
WHERE `valid` = 1
AND  `name`  LIKE '%%'
OR  `shortdes`  LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY `id` desc`

Comment: Looks like `$word` is empty, meaning you will get no results because nothing matches ... well... nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should order your active record queries the same way you order a regular SQL query...

SELECT

WHERE

order_by

$this->db->get(x); -- which is the equivalent of FROM.

IE:

```
<?php
$this->db->select('id, name, visits, shortdes, photo');
$this->db->where('valid', 1);
$this->db->like('name', $word);
$this->db->or_like('shortdes', $word);
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('products');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row(); 

   echo $row->id;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->visits;
     etcetc...
}
```

Or instead of using active records you can just use a full query.

```
$query = $this->db->simple_query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

Use the following user guide pages for more documentation:

active records:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

query results:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html